# How do you get a query set of all models in a Django (1.2) ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, django-orm, django-1.2

I have a Project model which has a pre-requisite attribute which is a ManyToMany field linking to other projects. That is, each project can have 0+ projects that must be completed before it can be completed.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    prequisites = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

How do I return all projects that are prerequisite to this project? I want to do something like this:

```
project_a = Project.objects.get(title="My Cool Project")

for pre_requisite in project_a.prequisites:
    # do something with pre_requisite
```

but `project_a.prequisites` returns a `ManyRelatedManager` object. The special _set attribute doesn't seem to be working either:

```
project_a.prequisites_set
AttributeError: 'Project' object has no attribute 'prequisites_set'
```

I'm thinking about modelling the pre-requisites in another model:

```
class ProjectPrequisite(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    prequisite = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

but I'd rather do things *the right way*, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`project_a.prequisites.all()`

Will return all `Project` instances connected through your manytomanyfield

a manager allows you to filter and get queryset objects as you would through the `objects` property of your models

this would allow you to do something like

`project_a.prequisites.filter(title='a_prereq_title')`

Comment: Ah, so simple! Thanks. Now I have a slightly different issue, when I mark project_a as a pre-requisite for project_b, project_b also becomes a pre-requisite for project_a. Perhaps I'm looking for a OneToMany relationship? Django doesn't have one of these.

Comment: @tompreston ManyToOne can be modeled by using ForeignKey I don't know if it will be trickier because the table is referencing itself https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Ah, but a ForeignKey only allows one project to be specified as a prerequisite. One project might have many prerequisites and any project might be a prerequisite to an infinite number of other projects. I'll create a new question after some more searching.

Comment: @tompreston good point with foreign key, i think your relationship can be modeled by setting `symmetrical =False` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical